# Foxx arangodb runs into memory limit

Tags: arangodb, aql, foxx

I have an simple query runs inside foxx

```
For u in collection
Filter u.someIndexedSparseFiler !=null
Return {_id:u._id}
```

This will return millions+ results. In the logs, arango have a message of limited memory heap reached and terminate the process.

```
reached heap-size limit of #3 interrupting V8 execution (heap size limit 3232954528, used 3060226424) during V8 internal collection
```

Even though I add the flag **--javascript.v8-max-heap 3000** to the start-up. It still runs in the same error. What should I do? Is there a better approach than this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're getting out-of-memory errors, but it looks like the data you're returning is overflowing the V8 heap size.  Another possibility is that something is  causing the engine to miss/ignore the index, causing the engine to load every document before evaluating the `someIndexedSparseFiler` attribute.

Evaluating millions of documents (or lots of large documents) would not only cost a lot of disk/memory I/O, but could also require a lot of RAM.  Try using the [explain](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/execution-and-performance-explaining-queries.html) feature to return a query analysis - it should tell you what is going wrong.

For comparison, my query...

```py
FOR u IN myCollection
    FILTER u.someIndexedSparseFiler != null
    RETURN u._id
```

...returns this when I click "explain":

```py
Query String (82 chars, cacheable: true):
 FOR u IN myCollection
     FILTER u.someIndexedSparseFiler != null
     RETURN u._id

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType          Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode        1   * ROOT
  7   IndexNode            5     - FOR u IN myCollection   /* persistent index scan, projections: `_id` */    
  5   CalculationNode      5       - LET #3 = u.`_id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: u : myCollection */
  6   ReturnNode           5       - RETURN #3

Indexes used:
 By   Name                      Type         Collection     Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields                         Ranges
  7   idx_1667363882689101824   persistent   myCollection   false    true        100.00 %   [ `someIndexedSparseFiler` ]   *

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   move-calculations-up-2
  4   move-filters-up-2
  5   use-indexes
  6   remove-filter-covered-by-index
  7   remove-unnecessary-calculations-2
  8   reduce-extraction-to-projection
```

Note that it listss my sparse index under `Indexes used:`.  Also, try changing the `!=` to `==` and you will see that now it ignores the index!  This is because the optimizer knows a sparse index will never have a `null` value, so it skips it.

If you aren't familiar with it, the "explain" functionality is extremely useful (indispensable, really) when tuning queries and creating indexes.  Also, remember that indexes should match your query; in this case, the index should only have one attribute or the "selectivity" quotient may be too low and the engine will ignore it.